# SQL and HQL retrieve data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

I've two tables in Mysql.

```
message -> msg_id(pk) and message(varchar)
track_record -> tr_id(pk), msg_id (foreign key), object_id (to whom the message is sent), profile_id(who sent the message)
```

Now i want to create a single query which gives me the messages and the sender profile id given the object_id.

E.g say i have the object_id 1.

Now i want to see all the message sent to the user with id 1.

Edited the answer to add my query which i tried

```
SELECT m.message, u.profile_profile_id FROm `message` as m, `user_track_record` as u 
WHERE msg_id IN 
      (SELECT message_msg_id FROM user_track_record WHERE object_profile_id = 1) 
      and u.profile_profile_id IN 
      (SELECT profile_profile_id from `user_track_record` WHERE object_profile_id = 1)
```

Want to do this in both SQL and HQL. 
Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @JBNizet
Can you please answer my question now ?

Comment: I mentioned my tables above... First I'm trying to do in sql query then i'll try to translate it to hql. The sql that i tried on my ENTITIES (message and user_track_record) is in the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query is much too complex.

Start with simple things:

Select all the track_records sent to user 1:

```
select tr.* from track_record tr where tr.object_id = 1
```

Now you would like the message linked to the track record. This is done using a join:

```
select tr.*, m.* from track_record tr 
inner join message m on m.msg_id = tr.msg_id
where tr.object_id = 1
```

Now you would like only the ID of the sender, and the body of the message:

```
select tr.profile_id, m.message 
from track_record tr 
inner join message m on m.msg_id = tr.msg_id
where tr.object_id = 1
```

In HQL, the query is almost identical. You have a Message entity and a TrackRecord entity. TrackRecord has a ManyToOne association with Message. It also has a ManyToOne association with the sender and the receiver

```
select tr.sender.id, m.message
from TrackRecord tr
inner join tr.message m
where tr.receiver.id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you... That completely my problem.
And yeah, that's my problem, i always go for a complex solution, Can u suggest the "Approach" for example as u said "start with the simple".

Comment: the hql above is returning list of object as i am getting it.
I created a pojo containing String messages and Integer senderId.
And i am getting the list through
Query query2 = session.createQuery(query.toString());
            List<UserMessages> messages = (List<UserMessages>)query2.list();

Any suggestions ?